# Subtracting from a recuring difference and storing it into an array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, difference, recurring

I have a riddle, practically it works this way.

You have a fixed originalValue which can not exceed 54; the plan is to get that value, subtract 6 and check if the diff or balance is greater than 12, if so subtract the difference by 12 until the reminder of that recurring difference is less than 12 then exit

```
  24 - 6 = 18;
  18 - 12 = 6;
  6  // the system exists why because 6 is less than 12
  // the goal is  store 6,12,6 in an array
```

This is my code:

```
int orignalValue = 24;
List<int> subtractabled = new List<int>();
int  diff = 0;
    
diff = orignalValue - 6;  // start sub with 6 and 12 for the recurring differences until the reminder is less than 12
subtractabled.Add(6);

while (diff < 12)
{
    if (diff > 12)
    {
        diff = diff - 12;
        subtractabled.Add(12);
    }

    if (diff < 12)
        subtractabled.Add(diff);  // get the reminder  
}
```

I have failed to loop through this and collect the subtractables. Maybe some hints on how I can solve this riddle? Thank you.

Comment: Your `originalValue` starts at 24. Then you `diff = orignalValue - 6;` followed by `while (diff < 12)`. But, `diff` is 18, so you don't enter the while loop. You should see this clearly with the debugger. This is a great chance to practice your debugging skills. By the way, your while loop lacks a closing brace

Comment: Think about the logic of saying "repeatedly if x < 12 check if x > 12".. Something is obviously wrong there, because an x you just verified to be less than 12 won't magically instantly become greater than 12

Comment: i think i have figured out a way . after looking at your comments

Comment: diff = orignalValue - 6;
            res = diff;
            subtractabled.Add(6);
            
            
            for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {

                if (res >= 12)
                {
                    subtractabled.Add(12);
                }
                else if (res > 0 && res < 12)
                {
                    subtractabled.Add(res);
                }
 
                res = res - 12;
            }